# Problem with try and if statement in a while loop

Tags: python, if-statement, exception

I thought I clearly understand the exception handling, while loop and conditional statements. But I came across this simple problem that my code execution never reaches the except statement.

I made the code as simple as possible to point out the problem.
So the code requires to press '1'. Only then it can escape the while loop. Anything else should go to exception. Characters, such as 'a' and 'b' does - because they cannot be converted to an integer. But any other number does not trigger the exception. It just goes back to the input step. Why is it like that? Clearly any other number except 1 is not equal to 1.

```
while True:
    click = input('Press 1')
    try:
        if int(click) == 1:
            print('correct')
            break
    except:
        print('wrong')
```

Comment: But why would there be an exception at all? As you state, an exception is only raised if the input cannot be converted to an int. If it can, there is no exception

Comment: why do you think it will raise an exception? *I thought I clearly understand the exception handling* maybe not

Comment: If you want to print something for numeric values that are not equal to `1`, you need to and an `else` clause to your `if` clause.

Comment: `int(click)` could raise a `ValueError`, but there's no compelling reason shown to convert `click` to an `int` rather than just checking if `click == "1"` instead.

Comment: When you *are* using `except`, never use a bare one. At *least* catch `Exception` to avoid catching things like `KeyboardInterrupt`, but you should strive to only catch the exceptions you care about or can handle properly. In this case, that would be `ValueError`.

Answer (score 0):

The code will go to exception only if there is an error. Which will occur if you enter a non digit character. But if you enter any digit other than 1, there is no error so control doesn't move to exception. You can create an error in case person enters a digit other than 1 using `raise` keyword.

```
try:
    if(int(input())==1:
        print('entered 1')
    elif(int(input())!=1):
        raise ValueError(' enter 1 only')
except:
     print('error')
```

Answer (score 0):

`except` is reached only when an exception is thrown. You can force your code to throw a `ValueError` when `int(click) != 1`. The following should do the trick for you.

```
while True:
    click = input('Press 1')
    try: 
        if int(click) == 1:
            print('correct')
            break
        else:
            raise ValueError('wrong')
    except:
        raise ValueError('User input is not valid')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing two things : **raising** an exception, and **handling** a raised exception.

What you want to do here is :

```
    while True:
        click = input('Press 1')
        if int(click) == 1:
            print('correct')
            break
        else:
            raise ValueError('Wrong')
```

You can then handle the raised exception using the try/except statements like this :

```
while True:
        click = input('Press 1')

        try:
            if int(click) == 1:
                print('correct')
                break
            else:
                raise ValueError('Wrong')
        except ValueError:
            print('Something went wrong with user input, but this except block will handle it')
```

See https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html for further details

Answer (score 0):

You don't need exception handling here; you don't care about the integer value of `click`.

```
while True:
    click = input('Press 1')
    if click == "1":
        print('correct')
        break
    print('wrong')
```

If you *did* care about the integer value, you would only want to catch the `ValueError` that `int` might raise.

```
while True:
    click = input('Press 1')
    try:
        click = int(click)
    except ValueError:
        print('Not an integer, try again')
        continue
    if click == 1:
        print('correct')
        break
    print('wrong')
```